# Linear positional encoding for Transformers with fixed sequence length

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, natural-language, transformers, attention

I am trying to use Transformers for a Time-series task (with fixed sequence length).

**Since it's sequence length is always the same, can I use a linear positional encoding?** I read some articles about this, and in all of them, the reasoning behind using a sinosoidal is possibility of varying sequence length. Is this not the case? Are there any other reasoning for using sinosoidals instead of a simple liner encoding?